# What exactly does it mean that a certain SQL Server version is no longer supported? Why are there different versions of SQL Server?

Tags: support, tags

On some occasions in this website, I've seen some people tell other people to remove tags like *[sql-server-2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2008) and [sql-server-2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2012), because they are no longer supported, and I assumed that it meant that those versions of the [RDBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database) can no longer be used.

I just told someone to remove their [sql-server-2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2012) tag, because I thought that they can't be using an unsupported RDBMS version, but a comment corrected me and said that it's in fact important to tag unsupported versions, meaning it can still be in use.

I've googled what exactly does it mean, and it appears to mean that it will no longer have updates, bug fixes, technical support and so on, so I guess I was wrong in thinking that unsupported versions weren't used.

But my question now is: Why did other users of the website say that tagging unsupported version was bad, and also what is the point of having different version if the next one is better? Wouldn't it make more sense to just update same version and that way you always support it?

Comment: It's bad to remove the tags because then we don't know what version of the product they are using and thus could suggest solutions that don't work in their environment. In the examples you give, SQL Server 2008 and 2012, they were both released *over a decade ago*; the product has moved on *a lot* since then.

Comment: It's not bad to tag those versions, but people may warn those users of the problem(s) of using unsupported software. SQL Server 2008, for example, ran completely out of support way back in 2019 and hasn't had a single security update since then. It does have security vulnerabilities, and they will never be patched. Not to mention that it lacks *a lot* of functionality taken for granted in more recent versions.

Comment: @Larnu So, in short, I've misunderstood the comments. They probably haven't told anyone to remove tags, but to stop using those versions?

Comment: Yes, the users should most certainly be making their best efforts to implement their upgrade paths ASAP. You would, probably, be surprised at quite how many of these users actually had no idea that they were using a product that was *completely* unsupported for 3+ years, so it's also educational for them.

Comment: "to just update same version" Wish it were that simple...

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, could you elaborate or send some link to a website explaining why programs like RDMBS get new versions instead of updates? The only think I can think of with my little computer/programmer knowledge is maybe the fact that computers improve, so they leave old versions for people that are still using less powerful PC's and then eventually stop supporting them

Comment: “Wouldn't it make more sense to just update same version and that way you always support it?” - As someone who routinely is placed in a situation where I must support a specific version of a piece of software, and will have that specific version for years, I would be incredibly upset if someone removed the version specific tag I selected from my question. Sometimes it’s not possible to update software, sometimes the version makes a difference, which is the reason the version specific tags exist. Don’t remove the version specific tags.

Comment: RDBMS aren't unique in getting updates, @Ineffable21 . Any *good* software does. Operating systems like Windows get them (i.e. Windows 10 and Windows 11, and you also have releases like 22H2 for those). PHP has versions 7 and 8, of which until last month 7.4 was still supported, at least for security updates, (now only 8.0 and 8.1 are). Products getting new releases and updates is just a "normal" thing, as is older versions losing support as a company can't be expected to maintain that many different versions simultaneously.

Comment: *"They probably haven't told anyone to remove tags, but to stop using those versions?"* it is also possible that they told you to remove those tags. This can be appropriate when it is clear that you don't actually use those versions or have multiple version tags which contradict each other.

Comment: @Ineffable21 Like most "infrastructure" software, RDBMS do not exist in a bubble. Instead, they are usually part of larger deployments where many software components interact. Installing small updates in such a system is usually an isolated work, but introducing any major version update can and does affect all components because the interfaces or even just subtle behaviours change. As such, older versions remain in use when the cost of updating is too large – say because there are no more experts for some parts of the system, or because it has limited expected lifetime to begin with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For SQL Server, at least, there are 2 levels of support; mainstream support and extended support. Mainstream support is when the version has full support from Microsoft and bugs, quality of life, and security fixes will be addressed in cumulative updates, and previously service packs. Extended support, however, only provides security updates.

When saying that a version of SQL Server isn't supported, this could actually mean that it's out of mainstream support or out of extended support. Speaking for myself (and for at least some other users I see in SQL Server related tags), when talking about a version that is out of extended support then the phrase "completely unsupported" will likely be used, as the version isn't getting *any* updates anymore.

Other products do follow similar idealogy as well, where a version will continue to get security updates months or years after it lost support for other fixes.

For any product it being unsupported doesn't mean you *can't* use it any more, however, it's often strongly advised that you *don't*. This is because, as mentioned, it won't be getting security updates any more, making such software a prime candidate for breaches.

Now in regards to the tags, as mentioned in the comments, removing version tags is *not* a good thing. Version tags are important as they let other users know what version the OP is using and thus what methodology can be used by those answering the question and also if the answer might work for a user reading the Q&A in the future. Technology moves quickly, and with each new version of software there are often new features, and some (older) features are removed; if the version tag is removed then the answers provided could easily be wrong for the asker, as they use removed or not yet implemented functionality for the version the user is using.

For those reading the answer in the future, if they see that the question is tagged with [sql-server-2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2019) and they are using SQL Server 2014, a future reader knows that any answers that they consume may not work. Conversely someone using SQL Server 2022 who reads a question tagged [sql-server-2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2008) knows that the answer (no matter how new) may not use the latest and greater features of their version, or even features that no longer work.

This, again, isn't just true for SQL Server; as I said features are removed and added to software all the time. Regardless of if the version is supported (completely, or just for security) knowing the version and adding that tag is important to the other users in the community.

Comment: SQL not the worst set of tags - at least it includes year. In C# it looks like people think that C#-2.0 is "newer than C#" and it takes some effort to clarify why OP wanted to limit answers to version that is almost 20 years old :)

Comment: People, for some reason, do confuse the year and the version, which can be quite frustrating, @AlexeiLevenkov . So people will talk about "SQL Server 2015", as they are using version 15 of SQL Server (which is SQL Server 2019), and vice versa they will say they are using SQL Server 14 (SQL Server 2017) and mean SQL Server 2014. Not to mention people think SSMS is a synonym for SQL Server (which is like thinking that Visual Studio is a synonym for C# >_< ), and that has different versions to the main product.